# "build_job() got an unexpected keyword argument" Error when jenkins jobs triggered through jenkins API

Tags: python, jenkins-api

`def runjob(joblist):
        server = Jenkins('http://localhost:8080', username='',password='' )
        for x in joblist:
                server.build_job(name=x,token="NRT")`
This used to run and trigger the job but started throwing this error now, I have unistalled py2.7 might this be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, there is a jenkins package and jenkinsapi package in python.

Both of them has .build_job() method but jenkinsapi doesnt allow to pass it in the above format. It was running as should when I removed the jenkinsapi import and added a jenkins. after the = in the code.